# How to forward Windows Identity in POST request ASP.NET WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, windows-authentication, dotnet-httpclient

I'm building a wrapper for old ASP.NET API service, which wants each request to be authenticated with Windows Authentication.

I've configured my wrapper to use this Windows Authentication for its endpoints. But I can't make initial authentication to be passed while making request in code-behind to that old API service.

Tried using `UseDefaultCredentials = true`, `AllowAutoRedirect = true`, `Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials`, `keep-alive` headers and various ISS settings, but with no luck.

I just want my wrapper to forward Identity, that was passed with initial request, to new request in code-behind.

I'm also finding info that it is not possible with NTLM. Is it true?

Comment: It was true you could do it, but MS has deliberately gone out of their way to disable that functionality due to ["Pass the Hash" attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pass_the_hash). You're better off at this point just using SSO and SCIM.